# Recodificar fatores a partir da frequencia relativa dos níveis e do valor médio de uma variável contínua

Tags: r

Tenho um dataframe com diversas variáveis do tipo `factors` que preciso recodificar. Um exemplo dos meus dados é o seguinte:

```
structure(list(ID = 1:100, faixa_etaria = structure(c(2L, 7L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 
6L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 
4L, 5L), .Label = c("menos de 18", "18 a 24", "25 a 31", "32 a 38", 
"39 a 45", "46 a 52", "53 a 59", "60 ou mais"), class = "factor"), 
    escolaridade = structure(c(5L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
    1L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 
    6L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 
    4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 
    4L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 
    6L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L), .Label = c("fundamental_incompleto", "fundamental_completo", 
    "medio_incompleto", "medio_completo", "sup_incompleto", "superior_completo"
    ), class = "factor"), renda = c(850L, 1750L, 4300L, 5600L, 
    3015L, 1540L, 1590L, 3100L, 1340L, 6780L, 4743L, 1050L, 4300L, 
    640L, 1050L, 13052L, 2015L, 1050L, 2030L, 1434L, 2180L, 1050L, 
    1980L, 4300L, 2240L, 1430L, 2912L, 1050L, 5413L, 2849L, 3753L, 
    6210L, 3602L, 3892L, 1050L, 4236L, 2813L, 3450L, 4109L, 3895L, 
    2112L, 2712L, 2445L, 4453L, 1350L, 3789L, 1050L, 1210L, 2500L, 
    2180L, 2312L, 1890L, 4299L, 3015L, 1050L, 5155L, 2015L, 3944L, 
    3127L, 1248L, 2180L, 1050L, 2389L, 7221L, 3218L, 1050L, 2912L, 
    1050L, 2424L, 2663L, 4103L, 1345L, 4117L, 3339L, 1050L, 9345L, 
    2356L, 3568L, 4123L, 3567L, 1956L, 1050L, 1050L, 3983L, 3431L, 
    5131L, 2912L, 1050L, 6721L, 2183L, 1731L, 1050L, 4236L, 4789L, 
    2891L, 5013L, 3562L, 3012L, 2873L, 3983L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))
```

No exemplo acima, deixei apenas duas variáveis `factor`, para ser o mínimo reprodutível. Mas há mais. Essas variáveis são "faixa etária" e "escolaridade". Além delas há também "id" e "renda".

A recodificação que quero fazer é a seguinte:

1. Quando um grupo/nível (`level`) de uma variável `factor` responder por menos de 10% dos casos,
   eu quero agregar esse grupo a outro, da mesma variável, que possua o nível (`level`) mais próximo,
   imediatamente anterior ou posterior.
2. Quando o nível for o inicial ou o final, só há uma opção de agregação (o segundo, ou o penúltimo, respectivamente).
3. Quando for um nível intermediário, gostaria de agregá-lo com aquele que possui a renda média mais parecida à do nível que será agregado.

Desculpem, mas não faço muita ideia de como começar. Pelo que li, imagino que seja com o pacote `dplyr` e com a função `group_by` e `mutate`, mas nao sei como calcular as frequencias relativas e fazer referência aos grupos mais próximos e utilizar essas informações na recodificação.

Comment: Repare que a pergunta pode estar mal definida: `faixa_etaria` só tem um nível com 2 ocorrências (exatamente 10% dos casos), todos os outros têm 3. Como fazer o agrupamento?

Comment: Prezado Rui, muito obrigado por sua tentativa e comentário. Acho que o problema foi que tinha incluido apenas 20 casos.  Agora inclui uma amostra maior dos dados (100 linhas).